# Data loading text on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've checked similar questions here, but none of them seemed to solve my problem.

I'm trying to add data-loading-text to my submit button, but with no luck so far.

I'm using Bootstrap 4!

Here is my HTML:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-2" data-loading-text="Sending...">Submit message!</button>
```

This was the last jquery code I tried:

```
$(function() {
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $(this).submit('loading').delay(1000).queue(function() {
        // $(this).button('reset');
    });
});
});
```

Thanks

Comment: if the button is type submit and is inside the form, once you click it the form already submits. You would only need to change the inner text with .text('text')

Comment: This feature has been removed in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Drop-in solution posted to the same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240011/show-loading-using-jquery-in-bootstrap-4-with-data-loading-text/#answer-53009288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style></style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function MyCustomFunction(){
            $("#submit").text("Loading...");
            $(this).submit('loading').delay(1000).queue(function () {
                // $(this).button('reset');
            });
        }
    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <button type="submit" onclick="MyCustomFunction()" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-2" data-loading-text="Sending...">Submit message!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

In case of Submit button the only possible way is to bind a custom function on click and change the action attribute to event handler.

Comment: If I chanege the type to button i can see the loading text, but then my form isn't sent.

Comment: @PapT In case of Submit button the only possible way is to bind a custom function on click and change the action attribute to event handler.

Comment: Still not sending

Comment: Sorry, it's sending the message now. But after the message sent the "Loading ..." text stays on the button.

Comment: You need to change that manually on receiving the response by $("#submit").text("Submit message!");

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most easy way to get the result you need:

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-loading-text="Your order is being processed...">Order now</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY:

```
$(".btn").on('click', function () {
  var dataLoadingText = $(this).attr("data-loading-text");
  if (typeof dataLoadingText !== typeof undefined && dataLoadingText !== false) {
    console.log(dataLoadingText);
    $(this).text(dataLoadingText).addClass("disabled");
  }
});
```